# Funcion que cuenta los caracteres en Mayuscula de un fichero CSV en C

Tags: c, csv

He creado una función en C que cuenta el numero de caracteres que hay en un CSV pero ahora necesito modificar esta funcion para que solo cuente los caracteres en mayúscula del fichero.
El código que cuenta los caracteres es el siguiente:

```
int contarCaracteres(FILE *archivo)
{
    int count = 0;
    char c;
    int charCount = 0;

    // Declaramos un bucle que vaya hasta el final de fichero, caracter por caracter.
    for (c = getc(archivo); c != EOF; c = getc(archivo))
    {
        if (c == '\n') // Para saltarnos la primera linea, la funcion empezará a contar carácteres despues de pasar por su primer \n, saltandose así la primera  linea.
        {
            count++;
        }
        else if (count >= 1)
        {
            if (isalnum(c)) // Verificamos que el caracter sea alfanumérico.
            {
                charCount = charCount + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\nHay un total de %i caracteres.\n", charCount);

    fclose(archivo); // Cerramos el archivo.

    return 0; // Si la ejecución ha sido correcta devolvemos cero.

}
```

Esta funcion funciona y cuenta correctamente los caracteres del CSV

Comment: una pista: `short chr_es_mayuscula(char c){return (c>='A' && c<='Z');}`, comprueba que el caracter sea mayúscula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo único que necesitas es cambiar la parte de la función que detecta si es alfanumérico para que detecte si es mayúscula. Tienes que cambiar esta parte:

```
if (isalnum(c)) // Verificamos que el caracter sea alfanumérico.
```

Por esto:

```
if (isupper(c)) // Verificamos que el caracter sea Mayuscula.
```

Esto esta en la biblioteca `ctype.h` que ya estabas usando con `isalnum`, te dejo el enlace de donde lo he sacado por aqui: [Biblioteca c.type](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/ctype_h.htm)